# Accessing nested fields in AVRO GenericRecord (Java/Scala)

Tags: java, scala, avro

I have a GenericRecord with nested fields. When I use `genericRecord.get(1)` it returns an Object that contains the nested AVRO data.

I want to be able to access that object like `genericRecord.get(1).get(0)`, but I can't because AVRO returns an Object.

Is there an easy way around this?

When I do something like `returnedObject.get("item")` it says `item not a member of returnedObject`.

Comment: I know I'm able to access the schema for the nested type by doing something like:

`parsedSchema.getField("toplevel").schema`

Am I able to then use that to decode the nested Object that GenericRecord returns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out one way to do it. Cast the returned `Object` as a `GenericRecord`.

Example (scala):

`val data_nestedObj = (data.get("nestedObj")).asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]`

Then I can access a nested field within that new GenericRecord by doing:

`data_nestedObj.get("nestedField")`

This works well enough for me.

Comment: For nested arrays, you have to cast as `GenericData.Array[GenericRecord]`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It says it cannot cast utf8 to GenericRecord

Comment: @deadpool that means your value is a string and not an object, so it can't cast to the `GenericRecord`

Answer (score 3):

You could use an avro serialization library to help you. For example https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s (I am the author) but there are others.

You just need to define a case class for the type of data you are getting, and this can include nested case classes. For example,

```
case class Boo(d: Boolean)
case class Foo(a: String, b: Int, c: Boo)
```

Then you create an instance of the RecordFormat typeclass.

```
val format = RecordFormat[Foo]
```

Then finally, you can use that to extract records or create records.

```
val record = format.to(someFoo)
```

or

```
val foo = format.from(someRecord)
```

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid using another library for something (seemingly) so simple.

Thank you for posting the link and the explanation!

Comment: If you want to keep deps down then sure, but Avro is a bit annoying to work with in this regard (lots of boilerplate to write converting from GenericRecords etc :(

Comment: I completely agree...it'd be nice if they added something like (or parts of) what you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

@rye's answer is correct and works fine, but if you can avoid the use of `asInstanceOf` then you should. So I wrote the following method to retrieve nested fields.

```
  /**
    * Get the value of the provided property. If the property contains `.` it assumes the property is nested and
    * parses the avroRecord with respective number of nested levels and retrieves the value at that level.
    */
  def getNestedProperty(property: String, avroRecord: GenericRecord): Option[Object] = {
    val tokens = property.split("\\.")

    tokens.foldLeft[Tuple2[GenericRecord, Option[Object]]]((avroRecord,None)){(tuple, token) =>
      tuple._1.get(token) match {
        case value: GenericRecord =>
          (value, tuple._2)
        case value @ (_:CharSequence | _:Number | _: ByteBuffer) =>
          (tuple._1, Option(value))
        case _ =>
          (tuple._1, None)
      }
    }._2
  }
```